# The variable is not visible outside the loop

Tags: python, scripting, materials, node-editor

I use this little script for a long time. .obj imported from Unity has some settings that i dont need in Principled node. For fix that, i remove all nodes except Image Texture and Material Output, create new Principled BSDF node with default Blender values and connect it with Image Texture and Material Output nodes. But by some reason that simple script stop work in new Blender version. Now i see error "NameError: name 'img' is not defined" on last code line. Inside the loop "img" and "out" variables defined by the same way and outside the loop link with "out" works well but not "img".

```
import bpy

for material in bpy.data.materials:
    if (material.use_nodes):
        nodes = material.node_tree.nodes
        links = material.node_tree.links

        for node in nodes:
            if (node.name == 'Material Output'):
                out = node
            elif (node.name == 'Image Texture'):
                img = node
            else:
                nodes.remove(node)

        principled = nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled')

        links.new(principled.outputs[0],out.inputs[0])
        links.new(principled.inputs[0],img.outputs[0])
```

Comment: It seems the `elif`statement does not get triggered, which means the image texture node is not actually called "Image Texture" Could you verify what is the name of the node in the node editor ?

Comment: It is triggered. If i put in print(img) i see "<bpy_struct, ShaderNodeTexImage("Image Texture")>" in log. And in case if that statement not triggered, all Image Texture nodes will be removed but its not happened.

Comment: But yes, inside node editor Image Texture node called like image texture loaded in there. Maybe is there way detect Image Texture node by type instead name.

Comment: Is it triggered in ALL the object's materials ?

Comment: Yes, and I found that in the new file, everything works fine with the new material.

Comment: Oookayyy... Even in new file with imported objects all work fine. Maybe something wrong with old file.